# how to convert mac address to decimal in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I want to write a function in python that take mac address as argument and convert that mac address to decimal form.please provide solution supported in python2

I have written a code

```
def mac_to_int(macaddress): 
   i=0  
   mac=list(macaddress)
   mac_int=0;   
 for i in range(len(macaddress)):
   mac_int=mac_int<<8
   mac_int+=mac[i]

return mac_int
```

actually in 3rd line where i want to copy content of macaddress to mac i just wanted to know that i have written correct way or not

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: actually python provide support of netaddr impoting which just writing int(mac) we will get mac address in integer form but netaddr is not supported in python 2.7 thats why i am asking about some idea

Comment: Well, do the maths by hand, then see if the answer matches that which your code produces. Then you will know if you have written it correctly.

Comment: You can do this quite simply in one line, though. Investigate `str.replace()` and `int`

Answer (score 21):

It is as simple as this line:

```
mac_int = int(mac_str.translate(None, ":.- "), 16)
```

This first removes the possible byte separator characters ("`:`", "`.`", "`-`" or " " but you can add more if you want) and then parses the string as integer with base 16 (hexadecimal).

---

As it has been asked for, the other way round could use e.g. `str.format` to convert the integer into a hexadecimal string and then just insert the colons back into it:

```
mac_hex = "{:012x}".format(mac_int)
mac_str = ":".join(mac_hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(mac_hex), 2))
```

Comment: i dont think this will work in python2.7 as int(mac) fn is applicable for python 3

Comment: This is no special function, it's the built-in `int`. It has been there forever.

Comment: @Byte Commander, is there a way to convert it back to Mac?. . I just bumped up your answer as it was very helpful to me..

Comment: @sunny I edited my answer and added some lines for that.

Comment: @Byte Commander, thank you - it worked!. Really appreciate it!.

Answer (score 0):

the following function will do the trick

```
import re

def mac_to_int(mac):
    res = re.match('^((?:(?:[0-9a-f]{2}):){5}[0-9a-f]{2})$', mac.lower())
    if res is None:
        raise ValueError('invalid mac address')
    return int(res.group(0).replace(':', ''), 16)
```